# How to pair bluetooth devices programatically without user interaction using react-native-ble-plx?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing, react-native-ble-plx

I am trying to implement a Bluetooth pairing programatically between a device and mobile app. I am able to pair the device but the problem is that it requires user to enter the passcode which I don't want in my app. I want to do that programatically. I need to provide the device name and the passcode programatically.
I am using the library react-native-ble-plx.
I could not find documentations related to this in the library.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What device are you connecting to?

Comment: It is a gateway with BLE

Comment: The gateway probably has secured characteristics which is why pairing is needed. There are different possible pairing methods that get selected based on the devices capabilities. The gateway developer probably selected the passkey method which is why your smartphones OS asks for the password. The popup asking for the passkey is opened by android/ios, not your own app or the library. If the passkey is required to connect this will happen with any existing BLE app and there is nothing you can do. Is there any mention of the pairing method in the gateway documentation?

Comment: Hi @M. Kotzjan,  Thank you for the information. Is there a way I could suppress this behavior in the adroid and ios Layers?

Comment: There are many questions about this topic on stackoverflow, many people want to do that as well. I don't think this is possible even using the default language (java, kotlin, swift, etc). This could be a good question for the maintainer of react-native-ble-plx. You can create a new issue here: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues

Comment: Thank you @M.Kotzjan